# Hiding the Keyboard on button click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am creating iPhone app which I show below.

At the end of screen I have text field. I have added a delegate for the same. As it is number pad, I have added button seperately so that when button is clicked, they keyboard is hidden.

Below is the code I have:

### .h

```
@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField006;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *doneButton;
- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender;
```

### .m

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn");
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing");
    // Ensure the relevant text field is visible
    CGAffineTransform translation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

    if (screenHeight==480 || screenHeight==568) {
            translation = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -120);
        doneButton.hidden = NO;
        NSLog(@"line 3");
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        self.view.transform = translation;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender {
    doneButton.hidden = NO;    
    doneButton.hidden = YES;
    [textField006 resignFirstResponder];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.textField006 resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Why isn't the keyboard hiding? How can I hide it?

> Keyboard == Decimal Pad Return key >> Go Auto-enable Return key =
>   Ticked

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Be sure to use [endEditing:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) if it's not currently hiding correctly.

About `endEditing`:

> "endEditing causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the
>   first responder status."
>
> "This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for
>   the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one,
>   it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the force
>   parameter is set to YES, the text field is never even asked; it is
>   forced to resign."

So, the following should work (inside your button click action method):

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift Version of @lifetimes Answer

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

it worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

You can also make `[self.textField006 resignFirstResponder]`

Comment: look at my code again. Its there already... WITH and WITHOUT self